# Namespace sys_Session_roles in oracle 12.2.0.1 works in sql query but not inside a plsql block

Tags: oracle, namespaces

This is an issue I am facing in oracle 12.2.0.1. We have recently migrated from 12.1.0.2. It worked fine there. `select SYS_CONTEXT ('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'ROLE_XYZ') from dual` will give correct results when executed as a sql query but not when executed inside a pl/sql block say a function.

Comment: Some code, actual and expected result would be helpful

Comment: SYS_CONTEXT returns the value of parameter associated with the context namespace at the current instant. You can use this function in both SQL and PL/SQL statements.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a definer's rights versus invoker's rights issue.  SQL and anonymous PL/SQL blocks are always run with invoker's rights, which means they run with all currently enabled roles.  PL/SQL objects by default run with definer's rights, which means they only have the privileges granted directly to the user and exclude roles.  The solution might be to change your function from definer's rights to invoker's rights.

Here's the `SYS_CONTEXT` function working as expected in SQL:

```
select sys_context('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'DBA') has_role
from dual;

HAS_ROLE
--------
TRUE
```

A function created with `AUTHID DEFINER`, or no `AUTHID` clause at all, will not recognize the role.

```
create or replace function has_dba_definers_rights return varchar2 authid definer is
begin
    return SYS_CONTEXT ('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'DBA');
end;
/

select has_dba_definers_rights from dual;

HAS_DBA_DEFINERS_RIGHTS
-----------------------
FALSE
```

By adding `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`, the function will now recognize all currently enabled roles.

```
create or replace function has_dba_invokers_rights return varchar2 authid current_user is
begin
    return SYS_CONTEXT ('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'DBA');
end;
/

select has_dba_invokers_rights from dual;

HAS_DBA_INVOKERS_RIGHTS
-----------------------
TRUE
```

---

The above code will *not* work when called from a trigger.  Roles are always disabled in triggers, and in any objects called from a trigger.  To find roles granted to a user, inside a trigger, you must query a table like `DBA_ROLE_PRIVS` instead.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution. Actually I had tried this but our earlier solution (on oracle 12.1.0.2) used a package to check the access and in there the "auth_id current_user" clause, since it can be only provided at the top-level program, didn't work and hence, I had struck-off this as a possible solution but yes, at the function level, as you showed, it does work. thanks again.

Providing here what I had tried (with the package) and which did not work. (I tried it again to check!)

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ADMIN_OWNER.ACCESS_CTX_PKG authid current_user IS
PROCEDURE SET_ACCESS ;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ADMIN_OWNER.ACCESS_CTX_PKG IS
PROCEDURE SET_ACCESS IS
Cursor c1 is 
select SYS_CONTEXT ('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'ROLE_XYZ') from dual ;
.......

Comment: @Angad Running it in a package worked for me.  You might need to provide a reproducible test case for us to figure out exactly why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: logon trigger SET_ACCESS_CTX_TRIG calls invoker''s rights procedure set_access_ctx_pkg.set_admin_access which checks whether SYS_SESSION_ROLES has ADMIN roles and accordingly creates context with the particular ADMIN role name as the value.

Comment: The issue is with the logon trigger. Invoking the procedure individually did give me correct results. exec SET_ACCESS_CTX_PKG.SET_ADMIN_ACCESS;

Comment: @Angad See my edit.  Things are different when called from a trigger.